# Encrypt data using private certificate inside android keystore

Tags: android, ssl, encryption, android-keystore

I am using a certificate file to encrypt data before sending it through Rest API. Currently, I am keeping it in `assets` folder.

I put the certificate inside the Keystore file which I am using to sign my APK.

```
keytool -import -keystore certificate.pfx -file CertificateFile.cer
```

Now the Keystore contains the certificate and listing it shows.

```
>keytool -list -keystore Certificate.pfx
Enter keystore password:

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your Keystore contains 2 entries

signingkey, Jun 19, 2015, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 83:C7:A9:D2:F9:80:C3:6B:16:49:FA:86:FC:18:D5:D5:
26:39:16:12
mykey, Apr 22, 2016, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): E9:85:A6:8B:8A:51:89:6D:EA:BA:B8:3A:25:BB:89:34:
1F:5A:BA:5E
```

But enumerating Keystore always has a size zero and aliases are not found.

```
keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
keyStore.load(null);
keyStore.aliases();
```

Comment: The key store used to sign the app does not (and should not) reside on the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up terms that sound similar but are totally different:

The one (Java) "keystore" resides on your computer and is used for signing your apps. It is a simple password protected file.

The other is the on-device "AndroidKeyStore" service. This service is a special service that offers the capability to apps to create & store their private keys in a protected section of the Android operating system. Only the app that has created the key can later access/use the key. The "AndroidKeyStore" is usually protected in a special way incorporating hardware protection functionality.